# How to render different directives using one ambiguous directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've taken over someone else's code and I am curious about something they were trying to achieve. Essentially it looks like this:

In html

```
<my-directive ng-repeat="directive in directives" dtype="directiveType"></my-directive>
```

He then has a service which looks like this

```
appName.factory('directiveTemplates', function () {
var templateMap = {
    directiveOne: '<directive-one/>',
    directiveTwo: '<directive-two/>',
    directiveThree: '<directive-three/>',
    directiveFour: '<directive-four/>'
};

return {
    getTemplate: function (type) {
        return templateMap[type];
    }
};
});
```

And in the myDirective.js his template function is this

```
template: function (element, attr) {
    return sfTemplate.getTemplate(attr.dtype);
}
```

There seems to be 2 problems with this, the first is that the dtype attribute is not rendering before he gets the value and even if it does render the template itself doesn't render and  appears in clear text on the page.

Is what he is trying to do possible?

Answer (score 1):

I would just use a single template that looks like this:

```
<div ng-switch="dtype">
  <directive-one ng-switch-when="directiveOne"/>
  <directive-two ng-switch-when="directiveTwo"/>
  ...
</div>
```

Add `dtype: '@'` to the `scope` of `myDirective` and Bob's your uncle.

Edit: missed the `ng-repeat`. I would just remove `myDirective` entirely, because the whole thing is just equivalent to:

```
<directive-one/>
<directive-two/>
...
```

Comment: I agree it is equivalent to that, but in the app users are able to order them differently, so it could be 

    <directive-four/>
    <directive-two/>
    <directive-three/>

etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried doing this in the following way.Im not sure if i got your requirement completely

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.dirType='directiveOne';
  $scope.dirarray=[{dirType:'directiveOne'},{dirType:'directiveTwo'},{dirType:'directiveThree'}];
});

app.directive('myDirective', function($compile,directiveTemplates) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    //require: 'ngModel',
    compile:function(tElem,tAttrs){
        console.log('Compile'+tAttrs.directiveType);
      return this.link;
    },
    link: function($scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
         console.log('Value received', $scope.dirarray[$scope.$index].dirType);
        var value= $scope.dirarray[$scope.$index].dirType;
        var template=directiveTemplates.getTemplate(value);
        console.log('In link'+template);
        var compiled=$compile(template)($scope);        
        elem.html(compiled);
    }
  };
});
app.directive('directiveOne', function($compile,directiveTemplates) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    template:'<div>Directive one</div>',
    link: function($scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
        console.log('In directive one');
    }

  };
});
app.directive('directiveTwo', function($compile,directiveTemplates) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    template:'<div>Directive rwo</div>',
    link: function($scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
        console.log('In directive two');
    }
  };
});
app.factory('directiveTemplates', function () {
var templateMap = {
    directiveOne: '<directive-one/>',
    directiveTwo: '<directive-two/>',
    directiveThree: '<directive-three/>',
    directiveFour: '<directive-four/>'
};

return {
    getTemplate: function (type) {
        return templateMap[type];
    }
};
```

});

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write("<base href=\"" + document.location + "\" />");</script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <my-directive ng-repeat="direlem in dirarray" directive-type="dirElem.dirType" ></my-directive>


   <!--  <my-directive directive-type="dirType" ></my-directive> -->
  </body>

</html>
```

I got the following DOM output

```
     <!-- ngRepeat: direlem in dirarray -->
    <my-directive ng-repeat="direlem in dirarray" directive-type="dirElem.dirType" class="ng-scope">
<span class="ng-scope">Directive one</span>
    </my-directive><!-- end ngRepeat: direlem in dirarray -->
    <my-directive ng-repeat="direlem in dirarray" directive-type="dirElem.dirType" class="ng-scope">
    <span class="ng-scope">Directive rwo</span>
    </my-directive><!-- end ngRepeat: direlem in dirarray -->
    <my-directive ng-repeat="direlem in dirarray" directive-type="dirElem.dirType" class="ng-scope"><directive-three class="ng-scope">
    </directive-three></my-directive>
    <!-- end ngRepeat: direlem in dirarray -->
```

Comment: Interesting, I think I needed to explain my requirements better but I think your solution can be adapted to work for it. The order of the directives is created by the user so it could be directive 4 then 1 then 2 then 3 for example.

Comment: Here since we use the directive array as the model for representing directives,we could modify this code to include a service which holds the array and provide API methods to manipulate the array as in reorder elements or add/delete.